# When using the await?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize with typescript. I know that the code is asynchronous, and 
 Here, I am using `promise`, and the code works..

I would want to know when I must to use await keyword ?

```
const promises = []
let tabIdDoc = requestedListIdDoc.toString().split(",")

for (let thisIdDoc of tabIdDoc) {
    promises.push(sequelize.models['Document'].findById(thisIdDoc))
}

q.all(promises).then((resultReq) => {        
    const lstDocs = []
    for (let MyDoc of resultReq) {
        if (MyDoc.matriculeDoc != "") {
            lstDocs.push(sequelize.models['FolderDocContent'].findOrCreate({
                where: {                       
                }
            }))
        }
    }

    q.all(lstDocs).then(() => {
        return response.status(201)
    })           
}
```

Is await keyword necessary here ?

Comment: `await` is only possible in an `async` function. But whatever you can do with `await` you can do without it (using `then` callbacks). NB: `return response.status(201)` is useless in your code unless you put a `return` before `q.all(lstDocs)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't ever have to use `await` as other programming using `.then()` can always get the job done, but there are numerous times when using `await` makes your code simpler.  This is particularly true when you are trying to sequence a number of asynchronous operations and even more so when you need to use previous results in more than one operation that follows.

**Example #1: Serializing operations in a `for` loop**

Suppose you want to save a bunch of items to your database, but for various reasons, you need to save them one by one and you need to save them in order (in other words, you need to sequence them):

```
async function saveItems(shoppingList) {
    for (let item of shoppingList) {
        // for loop will pause until this promise resolves
        await db.save(item);
    }
}

saveItems(myList).then(() => {
    // all done
}).catch(err => {
    // error here
});
```

Without using `await`, you'd have to use a significantly more verbose design pattern using `.reduce()` or perhaps a recursive function that you call on the completion of the prior operation.  This is a lot simpler way to sequence iteration of a loop.

**Example #2: Sequencing different operations in a function**

Suppose, you need to contact three different outside services.  You need to get some data from one, then use that data when you make a second API call, then use both of those pieces of data in a third API call:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

async function getPrice(productName) {
     // look up productID
     const productID = await rp(`http://service1.com/api/getID?name=${productName}`);
     // use productID to lookup price
     const productPrice = await rp(`http://service1.com/api/getPrice?id=${productID}`);
     // put both productID and price into the shopping cart
     return rp({uri: 'http://service1.com/api/addToCart', body: {name: productName, id: productID}, json: true);
}

getPrice("Nikon_d750").then(total => {
    // all done here, total is new cart total
}).catch(err => {
    // error here
});
```

Both of these examples would require more code in order to properly sequence the asynchronous operations and you'd have to nest logic following inside a `.then()` handler.  Using `await` instructs the JS interpreter to do that nesting for you automatically.

Some other examples [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Examples).

Several rules to keep in mind with `await`:

1. You can only use it inside a function prefixed with the `async` keyword as in my examples above.
2. All `async` functions return a promise.  If you have an explicit return value in the function as in `return x`, then that value becomes the resolved value of the promise when all the asynchronous operations are done.  Otherwise, it just returns a promise that has an `undefined` resolved value.  So, to use a result from an `async` function or to know when it's done, you either have to `await` the result of that function (inside another `async` function) or you have to use `.then()` on it.
3. `await` only suspends execution within the containing function.  It is as if the rest of the code in the function is placed inside an invisible `.then()` handler and the function will still return its promise immediately when it hits the first `await`.  It does not block the event loop or block other execution outside the `async` function.  This confuses many people when they first encounter `await`.
4. If the promise that you `await` rejects, then it `throws` an exception within your function.  That exception can be caught with `try/catch`.  If it is not caught, then the async function automatically catches it and rejects the promise that the function returns where the thrown value is the reject reason.  It is easy when first using `await` to completely forget about the error cases when promises you are awaiting can reject.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, I understand better. However, I'm using arrow typescript function, and I'm trying to use asynch keyword , but I have this error yet : await is only valid in async function

Comment: @AnaïsSaez You can put `async` in front of an arrow function as well

Answer (score 0):

You never necessarily *must* use `await`. You however *should* use `await` in every place where you'd otherwise have `then` with a callback, to simplify your code.

In your example:

```
const promises = requestedListIdDoc.toString().split(",").map(thisIdDoc =>
    sequelize.models['Document'].findById(thisIdDoc)
);

const resultReq = await q.all(promises);
const lstDocs = resultReq.filter(myDoc => MyDoc.matriculeDoc != "").map(myDoc =>
    sequelize.models['FolderDocContent'].findOrCreate({
        where: {}
    })
);

await q.all(lstDocs);
return response.status(201)
```

Comment: Thank you for your example ! However, I have an error with await keyword : "await is only valid in async function"

Comment: Change the `function` keyword of the function where this code is located in to `async function`.